# Best practice on git push after rebasing locally

Tags: git, push, rebase

As we know, git denies `git push origin BRANCH` after BRANCH is rebased with `master`. If I am the only one who is working on BRANCH, I can use `--force` while pushing, or simply delete the remote BRANCH and psuh BRANCH again.

So, I know the solutions to the problem but what I don't know is if my solutions have downsides. What is the best practice used by developers?

Also what is the safe/best way to handle the issue if more than one people are working on BRANCH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few points I can call from my experience:

- You choose to do rebase only in feature branches and never in master/dev so less people have to deal with that.
- Perhaps, drop a message in HipChat/Slack that rebase has happened.
- Remind them `git stash` is available to protect their current work.
- Your team members should use `git pull --rebase` in case change is easy to be perceived.
- It is still a common practice to rebase for hotfixes on master/dev branches, that is also a good opportunity to let your team members get used to rebasing.